# angular component get component width height after view init

Tags: css, angular

I am trying to get the component width and height after AfterViewInit. These values are used to draw on the SVG canvas.

TS:

```
  @ViewChild("svg", { static: true }) svgEleRef;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.initCanvas();
  }

  initCanvas() {
    this.svg = d3.select(this.svgEleRef.nativeElement); // correct svg

    console.log(this.svgEleRef.nativeElement); // print value
    console.log(this.svgEleRef.nativeElement.clientWidth); // print 0
  }
```

CSS:

```
svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: aqua;
}
```

`this.svgEleRef.nativeElement` shows clientWidth and clientHeight in Chrome console:

```
svg
assignedSlot: null
attributes: NamedNodeMap {0: _ngcontent-sab-c3, _ngcontent-sab-c3: _ngcontent-sab-c3, length: 1}
baseURI: "http://localhost:4200/"
clientHeight: 754
clientLeft: 0
clientTop: 0
clientWidth: 678
```

However `this.svgEleRef.nativeElement.clientWidth` prints `0`.

Any idea please?

Comment: Share the StackBlitz please...

Comment: Can u share a stackblitz  or HTML as well here

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-name',
  templateUrl: './component-name.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component-name.component.css'],
  host: {
    '(window:resize)': 'getWidthAndHeight($event)'
  }
})
export class CoomponentNameComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(){}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.getWidthAndHeight()
  }

  getWidthAndHeight(evt?) {
    var screenHeight : number = window.innerHeight;
    var screenWidth : number = window.innerWidth;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing everything right except the height in percentage. You should replace the height either with `px` or `vh` unit of the CSS.

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sof-q-59090280)

#### HTML

```
<div class="svg" #svg></div>
```

#### CSS

```
.svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: aqua;
}
```

#### console output

[image]

Comment: Hi @beewest, did you try this?